# How do I add an unstyled block with draftjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I know this is probably a noob question. I actually got this working by getting the block map from editorState and modifying it. This however feels hacky and I cannot help but think I overlooked something.

Essentially all I want to do is have an add button that allows a focused block to be added. Thanks for any help you can give me on this.

Comment: you're doing in right way-modifying contentState

Comment: Ok just wanted to be sure. Thanks!